# Reading a file in a different directory php

Tags: php, variables, file-io

I am trying to read a file from a directory 2 folders lower than the script.  The code works fine when the file is in the same directory but when its lower, it fails every time.
Here's My code

```
<?php
$logfile = '/pass/uploads/test.aes';
$my_file = file_get_contents("$logfile");
echo $my_file;
?>
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A filename beginning with `/` is an absolute name, and is relative to the root of the filesystem.

Remove the beginning slash if it's meant to be a name relative to the current directory.  Or, tack `__DIR__` onto the beginning of the name, like `__DIR__ . '/pass/uploads/test.aes'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
<?php
    $logfile = '../../pass/uploads/test.aes';
    $my_file = file_get_contents($logfile);
    echo $my_file;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use `../../` at the beginning of the path to go up two directories, unless the permissions on those directories are set incorrectly.

EDIT: as cHao said, adding `/` to the path will go to the root of the file system, which will almost certainly result in a permission error.