# PHP, Changing directory not working

Tags: php, linux

PHP Version: 5.4.16

I'm running an Apache Server on a Centos Linux machine and my PHP code to change directory doesn't work. My ultimate goal was to try and read a file that was in a different directory but it wouldn't read the file. My first attempt was

```
$filename=("/home/tom/notes/test_notes.txt");
$file = fopen( $filename, "r" );
```

This didn't work, so I fixed it up with the answer from this question: [Reading a file in a different directory php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243177/reading-a-file-in-a-different-directory-php)

```
$filename=(__DIR__."/home/tom/notes/test_notes.txt");
$file = fopen( $filename, "r" );
```

But that wouldn't read the file either, I then checked to see if it could read a text file in the same directory and that worked so I decided that changing the directory to where the text file was located could work.

I went around doing that with this code, but it doesn't change directory:

```
echo getcwd();
chdir("/home/tom/notes");
echo getcwd();
```

It returns:

```
/var/www/html
/var/www/html
```

(Without the newline..)

The directory is valid as cd /home/tom/notes in the shell, works

Any idea what is not allowing it to change directory?
Or are there any other better ways to read a file that is located in another directory?

(I used this code to see whether or not opening the file worked or not)

```
if( $file == false )
{
echo "ERROR: Unable to open file";
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error or warning ?

Comment: No, everything works fine.. although I'm not sure if I have showing errors enabled

Comment: when chdir() getting failed it must return warning. Do `var_dump` for your chdir code.

Comment: Oh wow, I just enabled error reporting and I get the "Warning: chdir(): Permission denied (errno 13) in /var/www/html/note_interaction.php on line 39" warning

Comment: @Tom than i hope it is clear, your apache user must have access to the folder. But more likely, all required files should be in a folder accesible by apache. Anyway, if you are not able to fix the permissions yourself, please update your post to fit the new question. (P.S. read this post http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is wrong with your `chdir()` code there must be some **warning** if its getting fail see the documetation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) try to debug your code for the same as below and enable [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php).

```
echo getcwd();
$response = chdir("/home/tom/notes");
var_dump($response);
echo getcwd();
```

To read the file see the example below. [More Details](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp)

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("/path/of/your/file", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```