# PHP: file_get_contents() force reading the file from server instead of cache

Tags: php

I am trying to read my constants from a JSON file using

```
$const = file_get_contents('/myfolder/const.json');
```

Problem is this will always read the file from cache and not from my local XAMPP server. During development phase, this file is dynamic due to edits and I end up clearing the browser cache everytime there's a change in the file. How can I force to read from the server always (latency in doing this during development phase is fine. I will switch to normal post deployment - how?)? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why not to specify the entire file path? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243177/reading-a-file-in-a-different-directory-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of "accepted" solutions.

The first is to add a timestamp to the file like

```
$const = file_get_contents('/myfolder/const.json?'.date("Ymdhis"));
```

You can also try this

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

I suggest adding one of these, clearing your cache and then try to run the code.  Adding the timestamp to the file has worked for me, when I add it before I start devving, and reloading the page.

Comment: Your solution will force the browser to invalidate the cache everytime.

Comment: Thanks @thomasw_lrd.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following to invalidate cache every time file gets updated

```
$filePath = "/myfolder/const.json";
$const = file_get_contents($filePath."?k=".filemtime($filePath));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a standard webserver like Apache or Nginx, the best idea would be to send a `Cache-Control` header, just what a browser does.

So, for `file_get_contents` you'd need to create a context resource like:

```
$context = [
    'http' => [
        'header' => "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n" .
            "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
    ]
];
```

And finally, the request:

```
$file = file_get_contents('/myfolder/const.json', false, $context);
```

---

Also, it probably isn't a good idea to depend upon the chroot provided by the server. Rather provide an absolute path to the file by `__DIR__ . /myfolder/const.json` which won't make you have to deal with all the pain with cache invalidation. Or, using something like `http:// . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . '/myfolder/const.json` which would again make you have to deal with all the cache PITA.